# Everytime I save a low variable, it returns the home page

Tags: low-variables

Everytime I click save on low variables page I end up on this url (below) but the homepage of my website is shown and the low variables are not saved.

http://locantro.com/admin.php?S=0&D=cp&C=addons_modules&M=show_module_cp&module=low_variables&method=save

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a `mod_security` thing. Hard to trace and figure out exactly what triggers it. Check [this thread on GetSat](https://getsatisfaction.com/low/topics/attempting_to_edits_to_variables_results_in_status_404_page_not_found#reply_10681587) and ask your host to disable or add an exception.

Comment: nothing from following that link (and its child links) solved this.

Comment: Ok, I have figured out it only happens with one low variables group, the other groups save successfully? The group that is not saving is only 5 wygwam fields with basic settings.

Comment: Figured if I move a variable into another group that works, I can save that variable. Doing them one at a time.

Comment: Looks like a similar problem to this: https://getsatisfaction.com/low/topics/problem_with_wygwam_low_variable Again, it seems to be environment-related; not sure what exactly triggers it. Must be a setting in Apache or PHP.